# NSURL url value not getting assigned

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

I'm trying to develop an app which accesses YouTube videos.

When I'm entering the name of the artist in the text field, the URL is not taking the name.

```
urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q= %@&format=1&category=music&start-index=11&&start-index=11&max-results=30&v=2&alt=jsonc",replaceString];

NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlString];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
```

The `urlString` is taking value when I'm trying to debug, but the value is not getting assigned to `myURL` and showing `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the non-ASCII characters in your hardcoded URL

```
urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

If you read the Apple Doc for `initWithString:` it states

> #### Return Value
>
> An NSURL object initialized with URLString. If the string was malformed, returns nil.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/initWithString:

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your pasted code, the problem is most likely the space character in your URL string, which I reckon shouldn't be there. But you should also take care to escape your query parameters too, as I describe in:

http://www.mikeabdullah.net/escaping-url-queries-in-cocoa.html